# I am giving here a O/P. I need the code using PHP and JAVA

Tags: java, php

This is clearly an interview question which ask by a interviewer today. I can't get the solution. Hope SOF will help me..

**O/P**

> 1
>
> 12
>
> 123
>
> 12
>
> 1

what is the code?

this should be done by both PHP and JAVA. And if it's possible kindly explain me the logic also.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any kind of comments on that "question" that the interviewer gave you?

Comment: All I can say is : printf ("%d \n %d \n %d \n %d \n %d \n",1,12,123,12,1);

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(1);
System.out.println();
System.out.println(12);
System.out.println();
System.out.println(123);
System.out.println();
System.out.println(12);
System.out.println();
System.out.println(1);
```

Comment: Yes, a stupid question deserves a stupid answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way, in Java:

```
public class RecursiveString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printString("", 1, 3);
    }

    private static void printString(String prefix, int i, int max) {
        String newStr = prefix + i;
        System.out.println(newStr + "\n");
        if (i < max) {
            printString(newStr, i+1, max);
            System.out.println(newStr + "\n");
        }
    }

}
```

Numbers are printed recursively. Not sure what more to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

```
string numbers = "";

for (int i = 1; i < 3)
{
    numbers += i.ToString ();
    Console.WriteLine (numbers);
}
```

Explanation 1: Numbers are incremented by one and appended to the end of the string.

Explanation 2: Some indication of the Fibonacci sequence (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5...) though it doesn't look quite like that.

Comment: And then removed from the end of string by one.